# What is the functional derivative of this expression?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

What is the functional derivative of the functional

$$F[f(x)]=\int f(x')^2dx'$$

Am I correct in thinking that we can utilise the product rule and set $g(x)=f(x)^2$ so that

$$F[g(f(x))]=\int g(x')dx'$$

and the derivative becomes:
$$\frac{\delta F}{\delta f}=\frac{\delta F}{\delta g}\frac{dg}{df}= \int dx' \delta(x-x')2f(x)=2f(x)$$

Is there any error in this calculation?

Comment: Could you please clean up what $g$ is? Is it $g(y)=y^2$ so that $g(f(x))=f(x)^2$ or is it directly $g(x)=f(x)^2$. By a reasonable standard, you would get $F[g(f(x))]=\int g(f(x))^2dx=\int f(x)^4dx$, which is probably also not what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

Usually one computes the functional variation as a directional derivative,
$$
δF[f]=\lim_{s\to0^+}\frac1s(F[f+s\,δf]-F[f])=\int_I2f(x)\,δf(x)\,dx
$$
and in general, for some function $g(y)$ in the integrand, $F[f]=\int_Ig(f(x))dx$ you get
$$
δF[f]=\int_Ig'(f(x))\,δf(x)\,dx
$$
so that one could write
$$
\frac{δF[f]}{δf(x)}=\frac{dg}{dy}(f(x))
$$